# Is it possible to override Values in Collections.Seq module?

Tags: f#

I have implemented IEnumerable for a collection I built, and (although I have not tested them all) the Seq values appear to work correctly. Is it possible to override some Seq values, for instance "last", when the native performance of a value of my collection is better than using Seq's IEnumerable based function? I have not found any information on overriding Seq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No -- the functions in the `Seq` module can't be overridden. However, some of them do try to optimize performance by checking their input value (the `seq<'T>` instance you pass them) to see if it's an instance of `IList<'T>` or `'T[]`; if it is, the functions will take some optimized code path. For example, if you pass an array (`'T[]`) to `Seq.length`, it'll be able to quickly determine the length by using the `.Length` property of arrays.

If you're stuck on using the `Seq` module, the only performance optimization I can think of would be to have your collection also implement [`ICollection<'T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13) and/or [`IList<'T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6). That may optimize some cases, but it won't be *all* cases.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I figured the answer was "no", but worth asking in case I overlooked something.

Answer (score 2):

As already said in the other answer, there is no way you can override the functions in the `Seq` module. If you're implementing a custom collection, then the best thing to do is to follow the standard pattern used by the core F# libraries.

- The `Seq` module contains the most often used functions and functions that can be reasonably provided for any sequence.
- Modules like `Array` or `List` provide more efficient implementations for a specific collection type and they add more functions (not available in `Seq`) that are specific to the collection (for example, functions `List.tail` and `Array.get`).

The best way when adding your own collection is to follow this pattern:

- Implement `IEnumerable<'T>` so that the functions from `Seq` module work for your type
- Create `MyCollection` module that contains efficient implementations of standard functions (at least those that matter to you) and adds more functionality that is specific to your collection.